# Installing Ubuntu on pen drive

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on 32gb usb 3.1 samsung pen drive. Booting from UEFI. I tried it on kingston also but with same issue: It gets stuck. I choose to erase everything and install ubuntu using all drive. Using encryption. I am using live usb (YUMI multiboot) to install on second usb

I can provide last entries in installation not posting it all because of post length limitation, last entry is where it gets stuck and installation continues infinitely:
...

```
Jul 11 13:28:07 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: get_path_to_storage_volume for volume disk-sdc({'ptable': 'gpt', 'serial': 'Generic_Flash_Disk_E5AD3FC5-0:0', 'path': '/dev/sdc', 'wipe': 'superblock-recursive', 'preserve': False, 'name': '', 'grub_device': False, 'type': 'disk', 'id': 'disk-sdc'})
Jul 11 13:28:07 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: /dev/sdc is multipath device member? False
Jul 11 13:28:07 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: /dev/sdc is multipath device member? False
Jul 11 13:28:07 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: found candidate disks [{'/dev/sdc'}, {'/dev/sdc'}]
Jul 11 13:28:07 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sdc'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
Jul 11 13:28:08 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Jul 11 13:28:08 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.387
Jul 11 13:28:08 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: devsync happy - path /dev/sdc now exists
Jul 11 13:28:08 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: return volume path /dev/sdc
Jul 11 13:28:08 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sdc'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.227
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: devsync happy - path /dev/sdc now exists
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: return volume path /dev/sdc1
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: volume_path=/dev/sdc1 found slaves: ['sdc1']
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: kname_is_iscsi: no iscsi disk found for kname sdc1
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: kname_is_iscsi: no iscsi disk found for kname sdc1
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: Running command ['mount', '-t', 'vfat', '-o', 'defaults', '/dev/sdc1', '/target/boot/efi'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sdc1'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/sdc1'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: volspec: path=/dev/sdc1 type=part
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: info[DEVLINKS] = ['/dev/disk/by-partuuid/1a53bf68-db25-3343-aaef-dbe699f8ee73', '/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_E5AD3FC5-0:0-part1', '/dev/disk/by-uuid/FCB8-D90A', '/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1']
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: configuring mount: mount-0
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: TIMED BLOCK_META: 246.457
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: SUCCESS: curtin command block-meta
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin: SUCCESS: running 'curtin block-meta simple'
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: builtin took 247.250 seconds
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: stage_partitioning took 247.250 seconds
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning: SUCCESS: configuring storage
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: curtin: Installation finished.
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: Skipping unmount: config disabled target unmounting
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: TIMED INSTALL_COMMAND: 247.252
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[5975]: finish: cmd-install: SUCCESS: curtin command install
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_event.3940[3940]:   executing curtin install partitioning step
Jul 11 13:28:09 ubuntu subiquity_event.3940[3940]:   executing curtin install extract step
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: start: cmd-install: curtin command install
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: unknown type for url 'cp:///tmp/tmpotqs2shy/mount', assuming type 'tgz'
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: curtin: Installation started. (22.1-43-g9e9f66e83)
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: merged config: {'sources': {'00_cmdline': {'type': 'tgz', 'uri': 'cp:///tmp/tmpotqs2shy/mount'}}, 'stages': ['extract'], 'extract_commands': {'builtin': ['curtin', 'extract']}, 'hook_commands': {'builtin': ['curtin', 'hook']}, 'partitioning_commands': {'builtin': ['curtin', 'block-meta', 'simple']}, 'curthooks_commands': {'builtin': ['curtin', 'curthooks'], '002-setupcon-save-only': ['curtin', 'in-target', '--', 'setupcon', '--save-only']}, 'late_commands': {'builtin': []}, 'network_commands': {'builtin': ['curtin', 'net-meta', 'auto']}, 'apply_net_commands': {'builtin': []}, 'install': {'log_file': '/var/log/installer/curtin-install.log', 'log_file_append': True, 'error_tarfile': '/var/log/installer/curtin-errors.tar', 'resume_data': '/tmp/tmpkoljkd3_/resume-data.json', 'save_install_config': False, 'save_install_log': False, 'unmount': 'disabled'}, 'reporting': {'subiquity': {'type': 'journald', 'identifier': 'curtin_event.3940.7'}}, 'grub': {'probe_additional_os': True, 'terminal': 'unmodified'}, 'kernel': {'package': 'linux-generic-hwe-22.04'}, 'pollinate': {'user_agent': {'subiquity': '0+git.1dbbc6f7_939'}}, 'storage': {'config': [{'ptable': 'gpt', 'serial': 'Generic_Flash_Disk_E5AD3FC5-0:0', 'path': '/dev/sdc', 'wipe': 'superblock-recursive', 'preserve': False, 'name': '', 'grub_device': False, 'type': 'disk', 'id': 'disk-sdc'}, {'device': 'disk-sdc', 'size': 1127219200, 'wipe': 'superblock', 'flag': 'boot', 'number': 1, 'preserve': False, 'grub_device': True, 'offset': 1048576, 'path': '/dev/sdc1', 'type': 'partition', 'id': 'partition-0'}, {'fstype': 'fat32', 'volume': 'partition-0', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'format', 'id': 'format-0'}, {'device': 'disk-sdc', 'size': 2147483648, 'wipe': 'superblock', 'number': 2, 'preserve': False, 'offset': 1128267776, 'path': '/dev/sdc2', 'type': 'partition', 'id': 'partition-1'}, {'fstype': 'ext4', 'volume': 'partition-1', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'format', 'id': 'format-1'}, {'device': 'disk-sdc', 'size': 28180480000, 'wipe': 'superblock', 'number': 3, 'preserve': False, 'offset': 3275751424, 'path': '/dev/sdc3', 'type': 'partition', 'id': 'partition-2'}, {'volume': 'partition-2', 'keyfile': '/tmp/luks-key-z6auxjwy', 'path': '/dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'dm_crypt', 'id': 'dm_crypt-0'}, {'name': 'ubuntu-vg', 'devices': ['dm_crypt-0'], 'preserve': False, 'type': 'lvm_volgroup', 'id': 'lvm_volgroup-0'}, {'name': 'ubuntu-lv', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '28160557056B', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'path': '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv', 'type': 'lvm_partition', 'id': 'lvm_partition-0'}, {'fstype': 'ext4', 'volume': 'lvm_partition-0', 'preserve': False, 'type': 'format', 'id': 'format-2'}, {'path': '/', 'device': 'format-2', 'type': 'mount', 'id': 'mount-2'}, {'path': '/boot', 'device': 'format-1', 'type': 'mount', 'id': 'mount-1'}, {'path': '/boot/efi', 'device': 'format-0', 'type': 'mount', 'id': 'mount-0'}], 'version': 2}, 'write_files': {'etc_default_keyboard': {'content': '# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE\n\n# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.\n\nXKBMODEL="pc105"\nXKBLAYOUT="us"\nXKBVARIANT=""\nXKBOPTIONS=""\n\nBACKSPACE="guess"\n', 'path': 'etc/default/keyboard', 'permissions': 420}, 'etc_machine_id': {'content': '2a219ad1a24c4575bc8518c5d8e1026b\n', 'path': 'etc/machine-id', 'permissions': 292}, 'etc_netplan_installer': {'content': "# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'\nnetwork:\n  ethernets: {}\n  version: 2\n", 'path': 'etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml'}, 'etc_netplan_installer_wifi': {'content': "# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'\nnetwork:\n  version: 2\n  wifis: {}\n", 'path': 'etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml', 'permissions': '0600'}, 'md5check': {'content': '{\n  "checksum_missmatch": [\n],\n  "result": "pass"\n}\n', 'path': 'var/log/installer/casper-md5check.json', 'permissions': 420}, 'media_info': {'content': 'Ubuntu 23.04 "Lunar Lobster" - Release amd64 (20230418)', 'path': 'var/log/installer/media-info', 'permissions': 420}, 'nonet': {'content': 'network: {config: disabled}\n', 'path': 'etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg'}}}
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: 'reporter' not found in config file.
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: curtin: Installation started. (22.1-43-g9e9f66e83)
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: {'WORKING_DIR': '/tmp/tmpt31xj534/scratch', 'OUTPUT_FSTAB': '/tmp/tmpt31xj534/state/fstab', 'OUTPUT_INTERFACES': '/tmp/tmpt31xj534/state/interfaces', 'OUTPUT_NETWORK_CONFIG': '/tmp/tmpt31xj534/state/network_config', 'OUTPUT_NETWORK_STATE': '/tmp/tmpt31xj534/state/network_state', 'TARGET_MOUNT_POINT': '/target', 'CONFIG': '/tmp/tmpt31xj534/state/config'}
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: start: cmd-install/stage-extract: writing install sources to disk
Jul 11 13:28:10 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: start: cmd-install/stage-extract/builtin: running 'curtin extract'
Jul 11 13:28:12 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: start: cmd-install/stage-extract/builtin/cmd-extract: curtin command extract
Jul 11 13:28:12 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: Installing sources: [{'type': 'tgz', 'uri': 'cp:///tmp/tmpotqs2shy/mount'}] to target at /target
Jul 11 13:28:12 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: start: cmd-install/stage-extract/builtin/cmd-extract: acquiring and extracting image from cp:///tmp/tmpotqs2shy/mount
Jul 11 13:28:12 ubuntu subiquity_log.3940[8962]: Running command ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p "$2" && cd "$2" && rsync -aXHAS --one-file-system "$1/" .', '--', '/tmp/tmpotqs2shy/mount', '/target'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
```

Please help!

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step) may help you make a working installed system in a USB drive.

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product/release; the `subiquity` implies it's a Server install, or you're using `ubuntu-desktop-installer` which sits above subiquity structures.. If it's 23.04 Desktop, another ISO with different installer `ubiquity` also exists; but it's easier if you just tell us what you're using.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 22.04 desktop installer

Comment: Your 22.04 uses Ubiquity installer which has this old bug for external drives: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Many work arounds in bug report. I prefer to partition in advance to make sure I have an ESP on external drive. I have installed many times to flash drives, but recent installs to external SSD worked so well & fast, I will not use flash drives any more. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: I am following those steps exactly step by step and still at loss because neither linux bootable flash creator works for me. I am thinking about installing portable Ubuntu 22.04 desktop on external ssd using live usb created with rufus. I had successfully installed ubuntu on my internal drive with automatic installation. Would be there anything except choosing right disk when installing Ubuntu? On pen drives I tried both automatic and manual partitioning with same resultat of installation hanging somewhere at 25%. Thank you for the link sudodus